# Non destructively enlarging HFS+ system partition

Tags: macos, partitioning, osx-lion, gparted, hfs+

How can I enlarge my HFS+ system partition?

I've tried GParted and other methods (the dragging scrubber is not available, even booting with installation DVD to ensure that the system partition is not mounted).

I've tried using the command

```
diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 limits
```

… but it doesn't work; it returns the message:

> Error obtaining resizing information (is this a Mac OS 9 compatible "wrapped" HFS volume?)

(and that volume is using HFS+ format)

diskutil list output:

```
/dev/disk0
#:        TYPE NAME                     SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:  FDisk_partition_scheme              *250.1GB   disk0
1: Windows_NTFS  Windows 7               63.4 GB   disk0s1
2:   Apple_HFS   OSX Lion HD             43.1 GB   disk0s2
3: Windows_NTFS  Datos                   121.1 GB  disk0s3
```

Comment: Hi, that question doesn't have a valid answer. I've tried using the command "diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 limits" but it doesn't work; it returns the message: "Volume format does not support resizing" (and that volume is using HFS+ format)

Comment: Ok, i've edited my question and i've added the diskutil list output (disk is using MBR)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can only resize volumes on disks that use the GUID partition table, not MBR disks.

See [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2374):

> Mac OS X v10.5 Leopard can resize any disk partition except a Master Boot Record Partition. You can use Disk Utility to see if a partition is a Master Boot Record Partition, and also to resize eligible partitions.
>
> Important: Resizing a Master Boot Record partition will erase all data on it, so be sure to back up important files on affected partitions first.

Comment: ok, but there are alternatives then? it doesn't mind if i must use a linux, windows or mac osx tools...

Comment: As far as I know, GParted can't grow HFS+ partitions anyway. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other tools to do so (given that Windows lacks support for HFS+ and that Gparted obviously can't do it).

Comment: thanks anyway slhck. I will keep looking for a solution... :`(